# how to connect public site with salesforce org

Tags: force.com-sites, microsites

I have a public website. I am using salesforce for keeping a track on jobs. I want only to post open jobs in my website from my salesforce org. Is it possible? and what could be the possible ways.. can anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this. You could create an API in Apex using REST, for example, that allows your public site to access data in your Salesforce org. A class that does this, might look like below:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/vacancies/bulk')
global with sharing class MyNewCoolAPI  {
  @HttpGet
  global static List<Jobs__c> show() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Jobs__c WHERE Status__c = 'Open'];
  }
}
```

For instance, when you make a GET request to `https://yourorg.my.salesforce.com/vacancies/bulk`, you would get a JSON response based on what the query in the class returns. In my case, it would just be all jobs where the `Status__c` field is "Open".

Alternatively, if you'd prefer your web server to handle things you could use `@HTTPPost` to send data to your web server and store it. For example:

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://yourwebsite.com/endpoint');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
request.setBody('{"name":"A Super Important Job"}');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
  System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
  response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
}
else {
  System.debug(response.getBody());
}
```

In this case, you'd be making a POST request to your site's endpoint: `https://yourwebsite.com/endpoint` that you can, for example, store in it's database.

You can learn more about REST API's on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts).

Comment: @geek_sfdc You're welcome. Definitely check out the Trailhead resource as it'll give you a much better idea of how to do this than I could write in an answer and don't forget to mark this as correct so it could help someone else in your predicament too. :)

Comment: apart from this can i use microsites for rescue?

Comment: @geek_sfdc Salesforce at it's lowest aspiration is just a database. So you can use a website hosted on GoDaddy to connect to it, an app hosted on Google Play, Force.com sites, really you can use anything to display jobs. I'd personally avoid redirecting users from www.yoursite.com to a site hosted on Salesforce, for example, that could get messy. But can you do it? Yep!